# copy set of every 3 colums to a new file in unix

Tags: loops, unix, awk

I have a file with 30 columns ( repeated ID Name and Place) and I need to extract 3 columns at time and put them into a new file every-time :

```
ID Name Place ID Name Place ID Name Place ID Name place ...
19 john  NY  23 Key NY 22 Tom Ny 24 Jeff NY....
20 Jen NY 22 Jill NY 22 Ki LA 34 Jack Roh ....
```

So I will have 10 files like these -

Output1.txt

```
ID Name Place 
19 john NY 
20 Jen NY
```

Output2.txt

```
ID Name Place 
23 Key NY
22 Jill NY
```

and 8 more files like these. I can print columns like 
`awk '{print $1,$2,$3}' Input.txt > Output1.txt` but it may be too cumbersome for 10 files. Is there anyway I can make it faster?

Thanks!

Comment: Check out https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Redirection.html which shows how to do the redirection from within awk instead of the shell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i+=3) {print $i,$(i+1),$(i+2) > ("output" ((i+2)/3) ".txt")}}' file.txt

#  output1.txt
ID Name Place
19 john NY
20 Jen NY

#  output2.txt
ID Name Place
23 Key NY
22 Jill NY

#  output3.txt
ID Name Place
22 Tom Ny
22 Ki LA

#  output4.txt
ID Name place
24 Jeff NY
34 Jack Roh
```

Comment: Thanks a lot jas! such a neat and efficient solution, I was trying to get similar loop too but it was not working. This is perfect.

Answer (score 3):

Tweaking a bit from this wonderful [Ed Morton's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14662249),

```
awk -v d=3 '{sfx=0; for(i=1;i<=NF;i+=d) {str=fs=""; for(j=i;j<i+d;j++) \ 
      {str = str fs $j; fs=" "}; print str > ("output_file_" ++sfx)} }' file
```

will do the split-up of files as you requested.

Remember the `awk` variable `d` defines the number of columns to split-upon which is 3 in your case.

Comment: Upvoted! For being a more generalized solution than mine.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '{for(i=0;i<=NF/3-1;i++) print $(i*3+1), $(i*3+2), $(i*3+3)>i+1".txt"}' file
$ cat 1.txt
ID Name Place
19 john NY
20 Jen NY
```

Comment: Thanks a lot James!